# how can I add a contact to a group in google contacts api v3

Tags: php, google-contacts-api, group-membership

I am trying to add a contact to a group in google contacts. When I try it in Google's "OAuth 2.0 playground" it works, but from my web-application, with exactly the same headers, method of posting and body, I get "error 400: bad request".

This is my code (php) :

```
$contact = '<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<atom:entry xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005"> 
<gd:name> <gd:fullName>Jack Frost</gd:fullName> </gd:name> 
<gd:email address="jack.frost@example.com" rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home"/> 
<gd:organization rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work"> 
<gd:orgName>Winter Inc.</gd:orgName> </gd:organization> 
<gd:phoneNumber rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home"> (206)555-1213 </gd:phoneNumber> 
<gContact:groupMembershipInfo deleted="false" href="http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/MY_EMAIL@gmail.com/base/MY_GROUP_ID"/> 
</atom:entry>';

$url = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/MY_EMAIL@gmail.com/full/';
$method= 'POST';
$headers = ["Host" => "www.google.com", "Gdata-version" => "3.0","Content-length" => strlen($contact), "Content-type" => "application/atom+xml"]; 
$result = $googleService->request($url,$method,$contact,$headers);
```

When I leave out the groupMembershipInfo bit, it works.

Joachim

Comment: google-contacts-api

Comment: see my new Answer below

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895784/how-can-i-add-a-contact-to-a-group-in-google-contacts-api-v3-with-php

Answer (score 0):

found it: don't forget to add xmlns:gContact="schemas.google.com/contact/2008" in your xml, so it looks something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<atom:entry xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005" 
xmlns:gContact="http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008"> 

<gd:name> ...
```

Comment: This does not seem to work for me. I presume it would have to with the `gContact:groupMembershipInfo` element?

Comment: Here you will find the Solution: https://vike.io/de/204411/

Or here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895784/how-can-i-add-a-contact-to-a-group-in-google-contacts-api-v3-with-php